# Sanitize HTML input using JavaScript server side and client side

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an attempt to create my own chatroom using npm, as it stands everything is working smoothly but my main concern is SQL injection or people entering HTML because it will parse anything entered. There is no form being used and the input button, text field and output are all controlled by JavaScript. below is the part of the HTML I am referring to.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bubble-container" ></div>           
</div>      
<div id="sendCtrls">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your message here" id="text">
    <button id="myBtn">Send</button>
</div>
```

This is my .php file which contains all the JavaScript.

```html
<script>
// -------------------------
//var name = prompt('What is your name?');
var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
var bubbles = 1;
var maxBubbles = 60;
var sock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5001");
sock.onopen = function() {
    var bubble = $("#wrapper");
    bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text">\
    <p><b>*** Welcome '+name+' to the chat!</b><br>\
    These are the rules, please read & follow them.<br>\
    1. Be polite in chat.<br>\
    2. Keep personal disputes out of chat.<br>\
    3. No advertising.<br>\
    4. Do not ask to become a Moderator.\
    </p></div></div>');
    myChat(bubble);

    sock.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: "name",
        data: name  
    }));
}
// --------------------------
var maxLength = 200; // chars per bubble
sock.onmessage = function(event){
    console.log(event);
    var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text"><p><strong>'+json.name+':</strong> '+json.data+'</p></div></div>');
    myChat(bubble);
}
// ---------------------------
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function (){
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    if(text != "") {
        if (text.length < maxLength) {
            document.getElementById('text').value='';
            sock.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: "message",
                data: text
            }));

            var bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text"><p><strong>'+name+':</strong> '+text+'</p></div></div>');
            myChat(bubble);
        }else{
            
            var bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text"><p>*** Your message exceeds '+maxLength+' characters!</p></div></div>');
            myChat(bubble);
        };  
    }
};
// --------------------------
var input = document.getElementById("text");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
}); 
// --------------------------
function myChat(bubble){
    $("#msgText").val("");
    $(".bubble-container:last").after(bubble);
    if (bubbles >= maxBubbles) {
        var first = $(".bubble-container:first").remove();
        bubbles--;
    }

    bubbles++;
    $('.bubble-container').show(250, function showNext() {
        if (!($(this).is(":visible"))) {
            bubbles++;
        }

        $(this).next(".bubble-container").show(250, showNext);
        $("#wrapper").scrollTop(9999999);
    });     
};
</script>
```

I have not included the server script which is also just JavaScript but can do so if needed. PHP has no interaction with what is being submitted. 2nd question is, will I need to write anything server side to protect against SQL injection or to prevent HTML being entered?

Comment: what database engine are you using? You'll need to use parameterized queries for whichever database you're using.

Comment: I am using xampp, these are the db info:  Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.1
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.1  by the way, none of the chat is saved to any database, it is deleted after 60 messages.

Comment: "I am making an attempt to create my own chatroom using npm" - NPM is a package manager. Do you mean NodeJS?

Comment: yes that is what I am using

Comment: I strongly suggest reading [OWASP's Cheatsheets on Injection](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) and other articles by that group.

Comment: ok thanks, I am new to node.js and I am not the best with javascript so to get this far without any help at all has given me a little confidence. I will mosey on over and have a look.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the js server and js client scripts never reads the mysql database because none of the chat is stored/saved. I was trying to ask if I should still be concerned about sql injection attempts through the html input or is it something i do not need to worry about?